# Grabbing 10 secs of audio file using javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to make an audio editor in javascript that allows users to grab 10 seconds of any part of a sound track, much like a ringtone app.
thanks

edit:
sorry, i meant to say, how would I go about doing it. I would also like to know if there are libraries that provide support to this.

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried? what is not working?

Comment: What's the problem you faced? Please ask a specific question. Your statement sounds too much like "Plz give me the code" or "Plz design my app for me"

Comment: _"I would also like to know if there are libraries that provide support to this."_ Asking for library recommendations is off-topic for SO.

Comment: What? Are you serious?

Answer (score 3):

Audio Editing is a tall order for Javascript, I would suggest doing a task like this server side. FFMPEG makes extracting audio samples from audio files a doddle.

Though, you would need permission to run executables on your host; not something that many shared hosts allow. You could consider cloud hosting or a virtual server.

Comment: It's possible with the HTML5 audio api. Check http://plucked.de/ for example, or http://www.html5audio.org/